# Flex + Adobe Flash: is it possible to use?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

There is *Flash Builder* product by Adobe Flash.

Is it possible to use *Adobe Flash* product as *Flash Builder* when working with *FLEX* SDK? Have you *the experience*?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is sort-of. Flash can use the free FlexSDK compiler. But it cannot process MXML the scripting language used to create flex framework applications.

However, there is a great open source free tool called FlashDevelop which can do both and works with the Flash IDE, or the FlexCompiler. http://flashdevelop.org.

It does not a have the FlashBuilder design view, and its profiler is not as complete as the one in FlashBuilder. But personally I prefer using it.

UPDATE: Below a reply says that flash cannot use any other SDK. This is not completely accurate a this time (Adobe CS5.5) Flash has its own compiler that does not include any FlexFramework classes. And so there are at least 2 flavors of compiler for flash. One through Flash, and one through Flash Builder. 
Additionally there anyone can use the free flex SDK as a command line utility to compile swfs. This is what underlies Flash alternatives such as FlashDevelop, and the FDT Eclipse plugin, among other resources that compile swfs.

Answer (score 3):

> There is Flash Builder product by Adobe Flash.

The true sentence sounds like:

> There is Flash Builder product by Adobe.

Then:

> Is it possible to use Adobe Flash product as Flash Builder when
>   working with FLEX SDK? Have you the experience?

It is very unclear what exactly are you asking but I suppose the right question is:

> Is it possible to use Adobe's product Flash Builder when working with
>   FLEX SDK? Have you the experience?

So this question can be answered: Flash Builder (formerly Flex Builder) from Adobe is designed to deal with Flex SDK. To tell the truth it can't use any other SDKs than Flex SDK (considering Adobe AIR SDK as part of Flex SDK). So the answer is: yes, it is definitely possible!

The last part of question (Have you the experience?) can be answered by Captain Obvious. Of course we have. That's why we are here to answer your questions :)

Comment: Your first correction is OK, but the second changes the source sense. However thank you very much Constantier! I mean if you have such *practice* experince then answer my question otherwise do not.

Comment: The sense of the second was: 'Is it possible to use Adobe Flash (not Flash Builder) to compile programs with Flex SDK?'

Comment: Ah ok. Now I've understand your question :) The answer is: no, Flash Authoring Tool can't build with Flex SDK as far as it uses *.fla files as a source but Flash Builder uses ActionScript and MXML sources, CSS files and binary resources such as images and SWF movies as input of Flex SDK's `mxmlc` compiler.

Comment: Thank you! Point for your answer.